# Regarding a well-known tensor product formula

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

As we know, for a commutative ring $R$, an ideal $I$ of $R$ and an $R$-module $A$ we have:

$R/I \otimes_R A = A/IA$

My question is that does this result still hold in case $R$ is not a commutative ring?

Thank so much in advance.

Comment: SOmething went wrong with your question (formatting). Regards

Comment: Do you know of an explicit isomorphism $R/I \otimes A \to A/IA$ in the case that $R$ is commutative?  If so, check whether it is still an isomorphism in the non-commutative case.

Comment: Does (I+r)⨂a → ra +IA work? With an inverse a+IA → (1+I)⨂a !?!

Comment: You need to be careful about what your notation means if $R$ is noncommutative. In the noncommutative case, $\otimes_R$ usually takes as input a right $R$-module and a left $R$-module. If $R/I$ is to be a right $R$-module then $I$ needs to be a right ideal but $A$ needs to be a left module. And now in order for $IA$ to be a left submodule of $A$ you also need $I$ to be a left ideal. So $I$ is a two-sided ideal.

Comment: You know what made me rather confused is the comparison of two texts: First is a non-English textbook which uses the commutativity of R in proving this formula and even highlights it;;;however in T. Y. Lam's Lectures on Modules and Rings, in the proof of 1→2 of theorem 4.74, these two structures are identified "as usual",,,however the rings are not necessarily commutative.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that for a right $R$-module $A$ and a left $R$-module $B$ the tensor product $A \otimes_R B$ is, by definition, an abelian group which represents the functor $\mathsf{Ab} \to \mathsf{Set}$ which maps an abelian group $C$ to the set of balanced maps $f : A \times B \to C$, i.e. maps which are additive in each variable and satisfy $f(ar,b)=f(a,rb)$.

The isomorphism $R/I \otimes_R A \cong A/IA$ holds for every ring $R$ and every ideal $I \subseteq R$: A balanced map $f : R/I \times A \to B$ gives a homomorphism $f([1],-) : A \to B$ which vanishes on $IA$. Conversely, if $g : A \to B$ is a homomorphism which vanishes on $IA$, then one checks that $f([r],a)=r \cdot g(a)$ is well-defined and balanced. Thus, there is a natural bijection between balanced maps on $R/I \times A$ and homomorphisms on $A/IA$. In other words, $A/IA$ is a model for $R/I \otimes_R A$.